# Login system with password preset in variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables, authentication

I am new to php and I am trying to make a login system but somehow it does not work. I predefine the password in a variable and i created a function that checks if the entered password matches with the password in the variable.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php $validkey = "Test" ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_value()
    {
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if (password == '<?php echo $validkey; ?>')
        {
            location.href = "tafels.html";
        }
    }
</script>
<input type ="text" name="password" id="password" />
<button onclick="check_value();">Login</button>
```

Comment: JUST DONT DO IT IN JAVASCRIPT :o

Comment: Do you have any ideas then for me how to do it?

Comment: Please use AJAX or normal form submission and validate the data on the server

Comment: @W.Derycke when you do login-systems in JS every user can manipulate the code in his browser to get easy access to your side, without you ever notice it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the way a login process should work.
First of all the password should be hashed and stored in the database. **NEVER** store passwords as clear text.
Secondly the password validation should happen server side, in a PHP file.

To explain you why it's dangerous to validate a password in the front end, just check this part of your code:

```
if(password=='<?php echo $validkey; ?>')
{

    location.href = "tafels.html";

}
```

While the server processes your PHP script it will echo the valid password into the resulting HTML. That HTML will be then sent over to the browser. Let's say that the valid password is "p@$$w0rd", if you inspect the page's source code you're going to find this:

```
if(password=='p@$$w0rd')
{

   location.href = "tafels.html";

}
```

The server will have replaced this:

```
<?php echo $validkey; ?>
```

with the value of the password. And that will be visible to everyone. Not safe at all.

Comment: It does not have to be safe. It is for a webapplication for a restaurant that will be used by the servants on the little orderdevice they carry.

Comment: Still it's not a good practice. It's a very serious security flaw but one that can be easily solved by moving validation to the server side

Answer (score 1):

To give you a start, here is an example, but please take care of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36883388/3799829

A very simple and stateless (no memory / no session) example of login system

**login.php**

```
<?php

$password = 'Test';
$url = 'tafels.html';

if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] === $password)
{
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>You need a password to continue</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><button type="submit">Go on !</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```